# Get the exact X coordinates when doing onScroll in android

Tags: java, android, scroll, gesturedetector

I am using onScroll() method of GestureDetector to get the scrolling event.
I want to pan to left or right along x axis.

As per my usecase, I want the exact absolute X coordinates not the dx value.

```
public class MyGestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{        
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY){
}
}
```

suppose, center of the screen is 0th coordinate.
on panning left, I should receive
-1,-2,-3 ..... (extreme left)

on panning right, I should receive
1,2,3 ..... (extreme right)

Comment: `GestureDetector` isn't best way to achieve what you want. way better would be to handle `MotionEvent`s obtained by `Activity`. initial touch event have `ACTION_DOWN` `action`, then using `ACTION_MOVE` you are adding/subtracting x and y distances from initial value

Comment: Adding of coordinates to previous one would not do right,
because I want mid of the screen to be the 0th coordinate.

if I tap on say suppose at 1/4th distance from the start, it should not consider this point as 0th point.

Comment: well, so maybe do some math and subtract half width of screen and half height to x/y coordinates of every `MotionEvent`?

Comment: It worked!! :) 
Thankyou so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

e2.getX() will give the exact coordinate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).